# Render a page from different location in Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using the Play Framework 2.2 version. I know the basic routing of pages and links.
But I have a page called **index.html** (*not the default page in play package this is one of my own page*) I want the page located at this location to rendered.

> **C:\project1\myproj\app\www\index.html**

Now I have this changes in Routes file as

> **GET /masterpage        controllers.Assets.at(path="/app/www/","index.html")**

But I am getting this error **Identifier expected**

Any help is appreciated. :)
Thanks..

Comment: If you can provide where is your play project path ?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error `Identifier expected` because in routes you have to mention the data-type , try below url

**route**

```
GET /masterpage        controllers.Assets.at(path:String,pageName:String)
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would move www from app folder to public folder and in routes file

```
GET     /masterpage                 controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="www/index.html")
```

Comment: are you sure? tested on 2.2.1 (scala)